# How to set couchbase operation timeout in spring data couchbase?

Tags: spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have a simple spring project which try to retrieve a document from couchbase using spring-data-couchbase. I have configured the config by extending AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration. Everything works perfectly fine.

Since I use couchbase as a cache, now I need to set the operation timeout to a lower value. Anybody can shed some light on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a timeout for the CouchbaseClient you have to provide it using the ConnectionFactory. Sadly, the current version of spring-data-couchbase doesn't provide a simple way to do that.

The class responsible to create connection factories is [ConnectionFactoryBean](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/couchbase/core/CouchbaseFactoryBean.java#L156-L158), and it has a setter for the operations timeout, but I couldn't find anything for `@Configuration` classes.

Since you are extending AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration, you might want to override `couchbaseClient()`:

```
public class MyCouchbaseConfiguration extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

     ...

     private final CouchbaseConnectionFactoryBuilder builder = new CouchbaseConnectionFactoryBuilder();
     private CouchbaseConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

     ...

     @Override
     @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
     public CouchbaseClient couchbaseClient() throws Exception {
           setLoggerProperty(couchbaseLogger());

           if(connectionFactory == null){
               builder.setOpTimeout(myTimeout);
               // Set another parameters.
               ...

               connectionFactory = builder.buildCouchbaseConnection(
                   bootstrapUris(bootstrapHosts()),
                   getBucketName(),
                   getBucketPassword()
               );
           }

           return new CouchbaseClient(connectionFactory);
     }
}
```

Also, you can call directly CouchbaseFactoryBean but it's not a good practice if you are not configuring your application using XML bean definitions.

Here is the XML configuration just in case:

```
<bean id="couchbase" class="org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseFactoryBean">
    <property name="opTimeout" value="1000"/> <!-- 1 sec -->
    <property name="bucket" value="myBucket"/>
    <property name="password" value="myPassword"/>
    <property name="host" value="myHost"/>
</bean>
<couchbase:template id="couchbaseTemplate"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the docs, the correct answer is wrong. That's not the way it should be done...

When you extend from **AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration**

> Default settings can be customized through the **DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.Builder** or through the setting of system properties. Latter ones take always precedence and can be used to override builder settings at runtime too. http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.0.0/com/couchbase/client/java/env/DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.html

For instance, to customize the timeout connection:

```
@Override
protected CouchbaseEnvironment getEnvironment() {
        DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder().connectTimeout(15000);
        return super.getEnvironment();
}
```

There are other options that can be assigned this way.

Answer (score 4):

According the docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html ),

Here is the application.properties :

```
spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.connect=5000ms # Bucket connections timeouts.
spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.key-value=2500ms # Blocking operations performed on a specific key timeout.
spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.query=7500ms # N1QL query operations timeout.
spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.socket-connect=1000ms # Socket connect connections timeout.
spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.view=7500ms # Regular and geospatial view operations timeout.
```

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Data Couchbase 2, adding the following property in application.properties did it

```
 spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.connect=20000
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `queryTimeout` to set the value of operation timeout as shown below:

```
CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
                    .connectTimeout(50000).socketConnectTimeout(50000)
                    .queryTimeout(1000)
                    .build();
```

this will ensure you get the response within 1s.

use this link to get different available options:
https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/client-settings.html#timeout-options