# Setting couchbase query timeout doesn't works

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am trying to **customize the timeout settings for my couchbase Spring Boot client**. I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase` in my project. Specifically what I want to do is, when it's taking too long for the couchbase to respond(may be say because of some network partition or any other reason). I just want to send some default response to my client. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326482/how-to-set-couchbase-operation-timeout-in-spring-data-couchbase) and am also using `AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration` to configure the timeout but it is just not working.

Below is the overridden method from my configuration class.

```
@Override
protected CouchbaseEnvironment getEnvironment() {
    DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
    .connectTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2))
    .maxRequestLifetime(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2))
    .socketConnectTimeout(1000).queryTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));

    return super.getEnvironment();
}
```

Can someone please help me with this?